# Strange dangerous behaviour: Printing all table contents automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using PaperClip gem in my project.

index.html.erb:

```
<h1 class="current-category">
<%= params[:category] %></h1>

<% if @books.count == 0 %>
    <h1>There are no books in this category</h1>
<%else%>
    <div class="row">
    <%= @books.each do |book| %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="/books/<%= book.id %>" >
        <%= image_tag book.book_img.url(:book_index), class: "book" %>

    </a>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

The problem is that index.html.erb is showing all the images as well as the entire content of the Book database.

I am adding a screenshot of that below. It seems as a bug in paperclip gem. Or What is the mistake I am making?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `=` from below line.

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
```